# Harvard CS50P PSET 4: TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Tags: python, cs50

I'm attempting to solve this problem : https://cs50.harvard.edu/python/2022/psets/4/figlet/

However, each time I run it, a TypeError pops up saying "'list' object is not callable". Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
from pyfiglet import Figlet
import sys
import random
figlet = Figlet()

if len(sys.argv) == 1:
    randomness = True
elif len(sys.argv) == 3 and (sys.argv([1] == "-f" or sys.argv([1]) == "--font")):
    randomness = False
else:
    sys.exit("Invalid Usage")

msg = input("Input:")
random_font = random.choice(figlet.getFonts())

if randomness == True:
    figlet.setFont(font=random_font)
    print(figlet.renderText(msg))

elif randomness == False:
    figlet.setFont(font=sys.argv([2]))
    print(figlet.renderText(msg))
```

Comment: The code works for me, can you show the whole error?

Comment: Problem_Set_#4/figlet/ $ python figlet.py -f slant
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/workspaces/106988985/Problem_Set_#4/figlet/figlet.py", line 8, in <module>
    elif len(sys.argv) == 3 and (sys.argv([1] == "-f" or sys.argv([1]) == "--font")):
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment the error is in the `elif` statement mainly this part:
`(sys.argv([1] == "-f" or sys.argv([1]) == "--font"))`

`sys.argv` is a list, but you were calling it with the list parameters. Instead of doing calling it `sys.argv([1])` you can directly use it `sys.argv[1]`.
Removing the parentheses would make this:

```
elif len(sys.argv) == 3 and (sys.argv[1] == "-f" or sys.argv[1] == "--font"):
```